# Referencing WMP under .NET

Tags: .net, windows-media-player, wmp

I can add the reference to Windows Media Player, but I don't get to the point where I could say

```
Dim newPlayList As WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist = wmpControl.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("soundsToPlay")
```

The WMPLib seems to be missing.

I can drag the WindowsMediaPlayer onto a form, but the WMPLib is missing for me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It can be found under the COM tab in the Add reference dialog.

Comment: @M.Babcock Not for me, when I type "WMP", nothing shows up.

Comment: It's called Windows Media Player in my list. If it doesn't show up then confirm it's installed.

Comment: But I'm still having a problem.  IWMPPlaylist is not found. I thought it would automatically be available when I add the Windows Media Player reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it. I had to rightclick the Toolbox bar and choose "COM" -> "Windows Media Player". 
Referencing it did not work.

Then I had to say

```
Dim nPlayLists As WMPLib.IWMPPlaylistArray = Me.wmp1.playlistCollection.getAll 'IWMPPlaylistArray
```

But this still doesn't work:

```
For Each nP As WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist In nPlayLists
```

The error I'm getting is "nPlayLists is not an enumeration".